# Using rsync to back up my Arch Linux distribution seems to have deleted my EUFI bootable drive. How can I fix this

Tags: arch-linux, rsync, restore

I am operating the March 2021 version of Arch Linux on a Dell XPS 13 9310 laptop.  I would list the Arch Linux kernel, unfortunately I cannot boot into my system to get it.  The linux distribution was installed with there `nvme0n1` partitions where`nvme0n1p3` was encrypted.

Last night I backed up my system using `rsync` with the following command that came straight from the Arch Linux Wiki;

```
 rsync -aAXHv --exclude={"/dev/*","/proc/*","/sys/*","/tmp/*","/run/*","/mnt/*","/media/*","/lost+found"} / /run/menu/username/backupname
```

Unfortunately I did not realize until after I ran the command that I also needed to include my swapfile in the `--exclude` command.  It appears that the backup did occur; however, with some errors.  As soon as the backup completed, I noticed that I had lost my wifi connection and was unable to re-establish it.  I decided to reboot the computer in the hopes that the reboot might fix the wifi issue.  However, when I tried to reboot the system would not boot at all.  I then booted into BIOS to find that it no longer recognized any EUFI boot devices.  Somehow, although I have no idea how, the `rsync` command deleted my boot device.

I have since booted from the Arch Linux iso on a thumb drive so I can use the zsh shell that came with it to view my mounted devices with the `lsblk` command.  I created two directories `/mnt/system` and `mnt/usb` so I could mount the `nvme0n1p3` and backup hard drives at them.  It does appear that the backup hard drive did receive the full backup.  I have tried to mount the `/dev/nvme0n1p3` partition to view its contents and see what, if anything was deleted; however, I get the error `/mnt/system: unknown filesystem type 'cryptoLUKS'`, which indicates and issue recognizing the encrypted hard drive, even though I did unlock it prior with the command `crypto setup open --type looks /dev/nvme0n1p3 lvm`.

I guess my questions are 1.) How would running `rsync` disable my computer like this? 2.) Is there a way to fix it and how? 3.) Or do I need to manually reinstall everything?  With respect to question 2, I am wondering if I can use the backup to fix this issue, even though it had errors, and being new to `rsync` how do I use it to restore everything?

Answer (score 0):

With that command line, `rsync` would only have been writing to `/run/menu/username/backupname`, which should have no potential to cause problems beyond a "filesystem full" error, so something else must have happened to cause the problem.

(Then again, typically `/run` is a `tmpfs` - effectively a RAM disk. So if `/run/menu/username/backupname` was not a mount point for a separate filesystem on backup media, then at absolute worst this might have caused a serious "memory full" condition, which might have caused some processes to be killed. But even that should not have had any effect that would persist after a reboot.)

Maybe something caused the loss of UEFI NVRAM boot variables - what does `efibootmgr -v` say?

> `/mnt/system: unknown filesystem type 'cryptoLUKS'`

This looks like you're trying to mount the encrypted drive directly, which will not work. The unlocking command should have created another device for accessing it in decrypted form, and if you also had LVM, they would act as another layer of indirection.

> `crypto setup open --type looks /dev/nvme0n1p3 lvm`

This looks like seriously autocorrect-mauled version of `cryptsetup open --type luks /dev/nvme0n1p3 lvm`. If that's what you actually did, it should have created a `/dev/mapper/lvm` for you, for accessing the encrypted contents of `nvme0n1p3`transparently.

Then, if there was supposed to be just a single filesystem, the mount command should have been something like:

```
mount /dev/mapper/lvm /mnt/system
```

But if you had LVM within the encrypted partition, as the parameters to the `cryptsetup` command suggest, the next steps should have been something like:

```
vgscan
pvdisplay /dev/mapper/lvm
vgchange -ay
lvs
mount /dev/mapper/<VG name>-<LV name> /mnt/system
```

If the commands `vgscan`, `pvdisplay`, `vgchange` and `lvs` result in "command not found" errors, try prefixing them with `lvm`, i.e. use `lvm vgscan` instead of just plain `vgscan`; in live-CD environments the LVM tools are sometimes packaged into a single binary for compactness.

Ideally, `udev` might have auto-activated the LVM volume group as soon as the `cryptsetup` command was successfully completed, and so the `vgscan` and `vgchange -ay` steps would be automatically done for you. But those commands will never hurt, and if something went wrong with auto-activation, the commands should also produce error messages that might tell what went wrong. The `pvdisplay` and `lvs` commands are for information display only: the first is for determining if the PV is successfully detected or not, and the second is for seeing if any LVs are successfully activated and to find out their VG and LV names.